# How to specify a subprotocol parameter in Python Tornado websocket_connect method?

Tags: python, tornado

I want to use Python Tornado for connecting to a websocket server using a specific subprotocol (lets call it "mySubProtocol"). I cannot find out how to do this with the `websocket_connect` method though. Its method signature is:

```
def websocket_connect(url, io_loop=None, callback=None, connect_timeout=None, on_message_callback=None, compression_options=None)
```

Now for testing purposes I am using a tool called "Dark WebSocket Terminal" where I can simply specify the subprotocol as a parameter following the URL like so

`/connect ws://10.1.45.195:8081/resource mySubProtocol`

In Tornado I have tried adding the subprotocol parameter after the URL divided by a space in the `websocket_connect` method's URL parameter but that leads to a bad request exception.

```
connection = tornado.websocket.websocket_connect(url="ws://10.1.45.195:8081/resource mySubProtocol", callback=self.onConnected, connect_timeout=30)
```

Defining subprotocols in a connect request seems to me like a common task, however I find very few information on this. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Kind regards, blomquist

Answer (score 0):

Actually just found out how to do it and wanted to let you know. You have to create an http header object and an http request object first like so:

```
headers = httputil.HTTPHeaders({'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol': 'mySubProtocol'})
request = httpclient.HTTPRequest(url="ws://10.1.45.195:8081/resource", headers=headers)
connection = tornado.websocket.websocket_connect(url=request, callback=self.onConnected)
```

That does the trick. Cheers, blomquist